# Java ClassLoader and XML file

Tags: java, xml, classloader

I want to access xml file inside JAR inside EAR but it fails.

My EAR structure is this one :

```
ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear
|_META-INF
|_lib
   |_log4j-1.2.17.jar
   |_ejb-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
   |_dtos-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
   |_configuration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      |_xml
         |_universes
            |_universes.xml
      |_META-INF
      |_log4j.xml
|_ejb-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
|_web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

So I want to access universes.xml in a singleton EJB stored inside `ejb-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

I tested :

```
InputStream ip = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/xml/universes/universes.xml");
```

Or :

```
InputStream ip = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/xml/universes/universes.xml");
```

and some differents packages notations without success.

My EAR is deployed in Glassfish V3.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, I found the correct writing :  `InputStream ip = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xml/universes/universes.xml");` but why ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(...) doesn't work...?

Comment: I think the problem might be that the jar has not been loaded by the  class loader since there are no classes in it to load.  If you put a class in the jar file (perhaps Configuration) and then ask it for its class loader you might be able to latch on to the xml file: Configuration.class.getClassLoader()....

Comment: many thanks Sticks it was the problem. You rocks ;)